# VB.NET mysql_native_password Access denied

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Que puede estar fallando?

El usuario tiene la contraseña: 8vQ3roQMyLAIgcws

He probado cambiando la contraseña y volviendo a entrar pero nada...

Os pongo el código para que os sea más cómodo copiar:

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class Form1
    Private cnx As New MySqlConnection
    Private cmd As New MySqlCommand
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            cnx.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=prueba;Uid=root;Pwd=8vQ3roQMyLAIgcws"
            cnx.Open()
            MsgBox("Conexion OK.")
            cnx.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos y gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probando he descubierto que tenía que editar este archivo:

```
/xampp/PhpMyadmin/config.inc
```

Y añadir la contraseña